# How to print a set in reverse order recursively in C++?

Tags: c++, recursion, stdset

I've tried the following code to print an `std::set<int>` in reverse order:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
#include <list>
#include <map>
#include <utility>
#include <set>
#include <stack>

using namespace std;

void setRecursivePrinting(set<int> s, set<int>::iterator it)
{
    int x;
    x = *it;
    it++;
    if (it != s.end())
    {
        setRecursivePrinting(s, it);
    }
    cout << x << '\t';
}

int main()
{
    set<int> s;
    s.insert(44);
    s.insert(2);
    s.insert(10);
    s.insert(8);
    s.insert(100);
    setRecursivePrinting(s, s.begin());
    
    return 0;
}
```

But the problem is the output doesn't show anything. Am I missing something? I'm aware about the `rbegin()` and `rend()` functions too, but I just want to learn to implement it in a recursive way.

Comment: You want to pass in `set` by reference, for one ... You keep making copies of it.

Comment: Your code fails if the set is empty.

Comment: Now I can understand what I've missed. All I needed to do was to pass the set by reference. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to be passing the set by reference and not by value.

Comment: It suffices to only send the set by reference. Sending the iterator by reference fails to compile. https://godbolt.org/z/qsdg03

Comment: Explain why this was a problem.

Comment: If s.begin() was initialized as a variable, you could pass it by reference. In above case it is a temporary.